# Crosstab multi columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Hello I have a problem with SQL in SQL Server 2005.

Suppose that I have a table called myTable with data as below:

```
|   NAME | CREDIT | GRADE | YEAR | SEMESTER |
---------------------------------------------
|  Name1 |      1 |     A |    1 |        1 |
|  Name2 |      4 |     B |    1 |        1 |
|  Name3 |      2 |     E |    1 |        1 |
|  Name4 |      7 |     F |    1 |        1 |
|  Name5 |      4 |     A |    1 |        2 |
|  Name6 |      3 |     C |    1 |        2 |
|  Name7 |      6 |     D |    1 |        2 |
|  Name8 |      1 |     A |    1 |        2 |
|  Name9 |      1 |     A |    1 |        2 |
| Name10 |      1 |     A |    1 |        2 |
| Name11 |      3 |     C |    2 |        1 |
| Name12 |      6 |     E |    2 |        1 |
| Name13 |      4 |     C |    2 |        1 |
| Name14 |      2 |     B |    2 |        2 |
| Name15 |      1 |     A |    2 |        2 |
| Name16 |      1 |     A |    2 |        2 |
| Name17 |      1 |     A |    2 |        2 |
| Name18 |      5 |     D |    3 |        1 |
| Name19 |      1 |     A |    3 |        1 |
| Name20 |      1 |     A |    3 |        1 |
| Name18 |      5 |     D |    3 |        2 |
| Name19 |      1 |     A |    3 |        2 |
| Name20 |      1 |     A |    3 |        2 |
```

I want to output the result as below:

```
|  NAM1 | CRDT1 | GRD1 | YEAR1 | SEMER1 | NAM2 | CRDT2 | GRD2 | YEAR2 | SEMES2 |
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Name1|     1 |    A |     1 |      1 |Name5 |     4 |    A |     1 |      2 |
|  Name2|     4 |    B |     1 |      1 |Name6 |     3 |    C |     1 |      2 |
|  Name3|     2 |    E |     1 |      1 |Name7 |     6 |    D |     1 |      2 |
|  Name4|     7 |    F |     1 |      1 |Name8 |     1 |    A |     1 |      2 |
                                        |Name9 |     1 |    A |     1 |      2 |
                                        |Name10|     1 |    A |     1 |      2 |
| Name11|    3 |     C |     2 |      1 |Name14|     2 |    B |     2 |      2 |
| Name12|    6 |     E |     2 |      1 |Name15|     1 |    A |     2 |      2 |
| Name13|    4 |     C |     2 |      1 |Name16|     1 |    A |     2 |      2 |
                                        |Name17|     1 |    A |     2 |      2 | 
| Name18|    5 |     D |     3 |      1 |Name18|     5 |    D |     3 |      2 |
| Name19|    1 |     A |     3 |      1 |Name19|     1 |    A |     3 |      2 |
| Name20|    1 |     A |     3 |      1 |Name20|     1 |    A |     3 |      2 |
```

Where

```
- Nam1= Name in Semester 1
- CRDT1= Credit in Semester 1
- GRD1= Grade in Semester 1
- Year1= Year in Semester 1 
- Semer1 = Semester in Semester 1

- Nam2= Name in Semester 2
- CRDT2= Credit in Semester 2
- GRD2= Grade in Semester 2
- Year2= Year in Semester 2 
- Semer2 = Semester in Semester 2
```

Please go to this URL to test this SQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/196c6/1 
How Can I create SQL to make output like this?

Comment: You specify SQL Server 2005 in the question, but it's also tagged with 2008. Are you looking for a solution which works in both or are you constrained to 2005?

Comment: Perhaps this answer might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284943/sql-server-2008-pivot-how-to-control-the-column-contents/4285558#4285558

Answer (score 3):

```
select
    s1.Name as nam1, s1.credit as crdt1, s1.Year as year1, s1.semester as semer1,
    s2.Name as nam2, s2.credit as crdt2, s2.Year as year2, s2.semester as semer2
from 
(select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by year order by name) rn from myTable where semester=1 ) s1
    full outer join
(select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by year order by name) rn from myTable where semester=2 ) s2
    on s1.year = s2.year
    and s1.rn = s2.rn
```

Comment: +1 nice answer, I spent 20 minutes with an awful PIVOT solution that was obviously over-thinking it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I was doing the same thing. this is much easier

Comment: When I saw it, I thought PIVOT too. I gave up on figuring out how it could be pivotted sooner though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like doing an outer join, when a simple group by is sufficient:

```
select max(case when semester = 1 then Name end) as name1,
       max(case when semester = 1 then credit end) as credit1,
       max(case when semester = 1 then year end) as year1,
       max(case when semester = 1 then semester end) as semester1,
       max(case when semester = 2 then Name end) as name2,
       max(case when semester = 2 then credit end) as credit2,
       max(case when semester = 2 then year end) as year2,
       max(case when semester = 2 then semester end) as semester2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by semester order by name) as rownum
      from t
     ) t2
group by rownum
order by rownum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Name,credit, grade, year,semester from myTable
group by semester,year, Name,credit, grade;
```

now we have to make a dynamic query with this previous query:
create as temporary table as there are semster first
create dynamically a select query with all fields of all semester table in a loop:
foreach temporary table concat all fields of this table in select query
and add construct label field with semester value of this table
and add temporary table with union

'select' + #tbls1.fieldName + ',' + ... + + #tbls2.fieldName +